# Haskell: "Could not deduce"

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck at a problem with my Haskell code. This is the simplified code:

> ```
> class MyClass a where
>     myConst :: a
>     myFunc :: a -> a
> instance MyClass Int where
>     myConst = 3 
>     myFunc = \x -> 3
> data MyType a =
>     Ctor a
>
> doit :: MyClass a => MyType a -> MyType a 
> doit x = myFunc x
> -- doit x = myConst
> ```

The error message:

> ```
> Could not deduce (MyClass (MyType a)) arising from a use of `myFunc'
> from the context (MyClass a)
>   bound by the type signature for
>              doit :: MyClass a => MyType a -> MyType a
>   at ...\Example.hs:12:9-37
> In the expression: myFunc x
> In an equation for doit: doit x = myFunc x
> ```

I'm very new to Haskell, but imho doit knows that the parameter is constrained to MyClass and thus provides myFunc/myConst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myFunc` takes a `MyClass` value as an argument, but in `doit` you're passing it a value of type `MyType a`, which is not known to be an instance of `MyClass`.  Did you perhaps mean to call `myFunc` on the `a` value inside `x`?

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem now. But how do I get the "a"?

Comment: @Stone you could write `doit (Ctor x) = Ctor (myFunc x)`.